# How to find the network interface of a server listening on 0.0.0.0 in cpp in linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, networking, ip

I have a server written in cpp. It is listening on 0.0.0.0. Now i want to find the network interface from where the server receives the packet. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use [`getsockname()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html) to get the IP-address the socket descriptor receiving the packets is bound to.
2. Then use [`getifaddr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) to loop over the interfaces available, to find which one matches the IP-address found in the 1st step.

Comment: I am using the same thing rite now. But sometimes getsockname() is giving ip address , for which there is no interface.(That ip is not there when we do an ifconfig) Any idea why it is like that?

Comment: @user2599593: "*Sometimes*" is to vague to conclude anything ... try setting up an example an post it as question here. However, this should not happen. Perhaps an interface went down after the call to `getsochname()` and before the call to `ifconfig`?